# Rails 4 Use Redis With Postgresql for followers/following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

I would like to model following/followers between users in a Rails app and found these 2 useful resources :

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html

The benefits of using Redis are clear to me, but I am not used to persisting a model outside of postgres.

Can they both be used together, Redis for fastening the queries, and postgres to have the data persisted in the database as well or is it unuseful duplicate data?

For instance a follow method using both would look like:

```
#User.rb

def follow!(user)
  # Save in the DB
  active_relationships.create(followed_id: user.id)

  # Save to Redis
  $redis.multi do
    $redis.sadd(self.redis_key(:following), user.id)
    $redis.sadd(user.redis_key(:followers), self.id)
  end
end
```

With all counting methods unsing Redis

```
# number of users being followed
def following_count
  $redis.scard(self.redis_key(:following))
end
```

Comment: You answered your question: 'Redis for fastening the queries'. They have to  present side by side.

Comment: So the persisted data in the database is only there as a back up?

Comment: No. Redis and others key/value memory data stores are used for different tasks like store session, caching, statistics etc. They store and read data very quickly (in comparing with traditional DBs) using RAM. But if something goes wrong you can lost all data.